# factoextra: Error in if (xlab == "x") xlab <- "x value" : argument is of length zero

Tags: clustering

I just followed the [tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/30-advanced-clustering/105-dbscan-density-based-clustering-essentials/) trying to do clustering on my own data, but I can't visualize it because `fviz_cluster` function is giving me an error:

> Error in if (xlab == "x") xlab <- "x value" : argument is of length zero

Here is the code I am running:

```
library("fpc")
db <- fpc::dbscan(rtsne$Y, eps = 0.15, MinPts = 5)
# Plot DBSCAN results
library("factoextra")
fviz_cluster(db, data = rtsne$Y, stand = FALSE,
        ellipse = FALSE, show.clust.cent = FALSE,
         geom = "point",palette = "jco", ggtheme = theme_classic())
```

How can I make `fviz_cluster` function working?

> Update

Filed a bug: https://github.com/kassambara/factoextra/issues/62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found an answer just accidentally. It is very unfortunate that `factoextra` documentation does not explicitly say that `data` parameter should be of `data.frame` type. In my case `rtsne$Y` was a `matrix`. The error that `factoextra` is giving is very uninformative.

Here is the code that ultimately worked:

```
fviz_cluster(db, 
----->  data = as.data.frame(rtsne$Y), 
        stand = FALSE,
        ellipse = FALSE, show.clust.cent = FALSE,
        geom = "point",palette = "jco", ggtheme = theme_classic())
```

Comment: I am using fviz_cluster as well, but for PCA clustering. I have a separate question that I've asked but haven't gotten the perfect answer, when you put geom = "label", where does it take the labels from? My guess would be the rownames, but the rownames in my data.frame are non unique. What do I do?